# Django: custom backend and custom user without changing AUTH_USER_MODEL

Tags: python, django, authentication

I wrote my custom backend that do authentication to a remote server. I want to use also the default django backend (so my admin django user can still login into the admin area), so I put my backend before:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
'myApp.backends.UserBackend',
'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',)
```

I also wrote my custom user for my UserBackend:

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    id = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), max_length=255, blank=True, unique=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
```

Then I wrote my `authenticate()` method that istantiate MyUser.

Since I want to use both user models (each for backend) and MyUser is used only in memory to hold json that comes from remote authentication, I don't want to edit AUTH_USER_MODEL. But the problem is that doing so, when I logged in on my backend, it is used User model, not MyUser.
How can I solve?

Comment: Have you tried returning MyUser instance in your backend's `authenticate`?

Comment: Yes, the authentication request is working; the problem begins from the first request after authentication onwards